# Magento is taking frontend\base\default\template\page/2columns-right.phtm path instead of frontend\default\new_design\template

Tags: magento-1.7

Recently I have applied one extension in my project. In view page CSS is not getting reflected since it takes path of base/default. But actual path is in default/new_design.

How to call default/new_design path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare the template path for your view page in your design layout xml, as below,

```
<yourextension_index_index>
     <reference name="content">
       <block type="core/template" name="yourextension" template="yourextension/yourextension.phtml"/>      
     </reference> 
</yourextension_index_index>
```

Then you can add the css to extension as below,

```
<action method="addCss"><stylesheeet>css/yourextension.css</stylesheeet></action>
```

Comment: no effect is seen

Comment: Refreshed the cache?

Comment: Yes I cleared cache

Comment: One more thing you can try. The phtml which are seen in base/default can simply copy to default/new_design with appropriate folder.